# Asynchronous REST-Call with OK-Message in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, asynchronous

Given a time-consuming rest-service, which is triggered by a Rest-Call. After invoking, the user should get a OK-Message, that the call will be processed and the service will continue asynchronously. Is there Spring-Support for this purpose.

I looked at @Asynch but it seems to deliver the Data asynchronously but not a synchronous OK-Response

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/poiimporter", "/poiimporter/{providers}"}, method 
 = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
 public String loadStaticData(@PathVariable(value = "providers",required = 
      false) String providers) {
// asynch call with save to database
// return "Process started"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "service will continue asynchronously"? Should the service return results via same response later, or is `OK` enough?

Comment: ok is enough, the result is stored in the database and can be fetched by another Rest-Call

Comment: How do you know that the result will be successfully stored before it is stored?

Comment: That is not part of the Response. It only says, that the process is started

Comment: Then just call async service that will do computation, and synchronously return `OK`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov could you provide an example?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The issue is that you don't know if the service will do its job. So returning OK, can be wrong some times. If Ok, means started processing, than it may  be.

Comment: Hey. If you need the result of time-concuming task use [DeferredResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html) Otherwise use [Async](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async)

Comment: @NiVeR, a service, by definition, cannot be assumed to not do its job if it returned `OK` in response. If something is wrong with request, then it should not return Ok response, simple as that.

Comment: Why aren't you using Executors framework?